# Where are the files UnityEngine.dll and UnityEditor.dll located on a Windows filesystem?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, unity, dll

Visual Studio can't find the UnityX.dll files after I copied my assets folder from one computer to another. Where can I find these .DLLs?

- UnityEditor.dll
- UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.XCode.dll
- UnityEngine.dll
- UnityEngine.UI.dll

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `UnityEngine.dll` and `UnityEditor.dll` can be found `Editor\Data\Managed` subfolder of your Unity installation.
- `UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.XCode.dll` is in `Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\iossupport` and
- `UnityEngine.Ui.dll` is in `Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\Standalone`

Comment: In the latest Unity (5x) the UnityEngine.Ui.dll is in:
/Contents/UnityExtensions/Unity/GUISystem/Editor/UnityEditor.UI.dll

Comment: C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.4.15f1\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll

Comment: UnityEngine.UI.dll is in "<PROJECT_DIR>\Library\ScriptAssemblies" for Unity 2020.3.